# How to put a canvas and a list in the same div

Tags: css, html5-canvas, html-lists

I am new to css3 and html5. I have several canvas and each one has text description in the form of a list. I want to put each canvas and its description list in the same div. What I havs now is canvas always under the list. When I have more pairs, all the lists appear together on the top and canvases appear under them.

html5 code:

```
<div class="detail-section">
     <div class="detail-section-text">
        <p class="detail-section-text-title">Description</p>
        <ul>
            <li id="Descriptiontext"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <canvas class="detail-section-canvas" id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.detail-section {
    margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
    width: 40%;
}

.detail-section-text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.detail-section-canvas {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

.detail-section-text-title {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

How cai I place the list on the left side and the canvas on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Should put the canvas on the right and the text on the left:

```
.detail-section-text {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0%;
}
.detail-section-canvas {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 20%;/* I don't think you meant to have 2 width deceleration's, pick whatever one is right*/
    height: 20%;
    left: 50%;
}
```